# Broadcasting the dynamically allocated 2d array using MPI_Bcast(...)

Tags: mpi

I have to create an array dynamically using malloc , the root process does this, then the arrays is supposed to be broadcasted to all the other processes who will print it for now, actually requirement is the other processes will change the value of the matrix independently. My main problem is im not able to broadcast the whole array to all the processes.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{   
    int **array;
    int rank,size,i,j;

    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&size);
    MPI_Datatype data_type;

    size= 4;
    array = (int **)malloc(size*sizeof(int *));
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
        array[i] = (int *)malloc(size*sizeof(int));
    if(rank==0)
    {
        int t= 0;
        for(i=0;i<size;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<size;j++){
                array[i][j]=t++;
                printf("%4d",array[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("size is %zu\n",sizeof(array));
    }
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Bcast(&size,1,MPI_INT,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    printf("size %d proec %d\n",size,rank);

    MPI_Bcast((int **)&(array[0][0]),size*size,MPI_INT,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    printf("process %d prainting matrix:\n",rank);

    for (i= 0; i <size;i++)
    {
        for(j= 0; j < size; j++)
            printf("%d [%d]\t",array[i][j],rank);
        printf("\n");
    }

    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Comment: You must allocate your arrays in contiguous memory. A quick search on SO will point you to several accepted answers.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with line

```
MPI_Bcast((int **)&(array[0][0]),size*size,MPI_INT,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

you should do

```
for(i=0;i<size;i++)
{
  MPI_Bcast((int **)&(array[i][0]),size,MPI_INT,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}
```

I don't know what was your intent but `sizeof(array)` does not return the size of the array but rather the size of an `(size_t *)` which is 8 in 64 bits.

**Long explanation if you want one.**

MPI_Send or MPI_Bcast really send chunk of memories.

To determine these chunks you have to give a beginning (first argument of MPI_Bcast or MPI_Send) then a length (second argument) then the type of data (third argument).

In your example it knows it must send from `&(array[0][0])` to `&(array[0][0])+(size*size-1)*sizeof(int)`

Now when you do

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{   
    int **array, * array_un;
    int rank,size,i,j;

    int **array
    size= 4;
    array = (int **)malloc(size*sizeof(int *));
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        array[i] = (int *)malloc(size*sizeof(int));
        printf("Ox%X\n",(size_t)array[i]);
    }
    printf("end array=Ox%X\n",(size_t) &(array[size-1][size-1]));
    printf("end pointer=Ox%X\n",(size_t) array+(size*size-1)*sizeof(int));
}
```

it outputs

```
Ox13B91A0
Ox13B91C0
Ox13B91E0
Ox13B6B90
end array  = Ox13B6B9C
end pointer= Ox13BB06C
```

As you see `end array` and `end pointer` are different. If you now look at the adress of each `malloc` the increment is 0x20 (which is more than `4*size(int)=10`) then suddenly decrement by 0x2650 !

Successive `malloc` allocate the memory with no warranty that the memory are allocated next to each other.

Therefore you cannot send using `MPI_Bcast((int **)&(array[0][0]),size*size,MPI_INT,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);` because the data between `&(array[0][0])` to &`(array[0][0])+(size*size-1)*sizeof(int)` does not actually contain the data you want to send.

However one `malloc` allocates a chunk of contiguous memory

so you can send `MPI_Bcast((int **)&(array[i][0]),size,MPI_INT,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);`

**To be thourough**

Setting up a send and receive has a cost and sending has a cost. So the less MPI_"something" call you do the better it is.

So your matrix should really be allocated with one `malloc`

Compare your modified code with this code

```
#include <mpi.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{   
    int *array;
    int rank,size,i,j;

    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&size);
    MPI_Datatype data_type;

    size= 4;
    array = (int *)malloc(size*size*sizeof(int));

    if(rank==0)
    {
        int t= 0;
        for(i=0;i<size;i++) { for(j=0;j<size;j++){ array[i*size+j]=t++; } }
    }

    MPI_Bcast(array,size*size,MPI_INT,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    printf("process %d printing matrix:\n",rank);

    for (i= 0; i <size;i++)
    {
        for(j= 0; j < size; j++)
            printf("%d [%d]\t",array[i*size+j],rank);
        printf("\n");
    }
    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Comment: IMHO the real fix is to allocate the memory in contiguous memory since `MPI_Bcast()` in a loop is highly suboptimal.

Comment: Also, it is way easier to keep an `int **array` so elements can be accessed via `array[i][j]` (even if this requires two `malloc()` for `array` and `array[0]` and array[1:size-1` must be manually populated)